# how to download a partial web page using .net

Tags: c#, .net

We are downloading a full web page using **System.Net.WebClient** class. But we only want less than half of the page. So is there a way to download a portion of the page, say 1/3rd, half etc of a page using .net library so that We can save the network bandwidth and the space? If so, please throw your ideas, thanks.

Comment: Is it your own website you are trying to view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an "Accept-Ranges header" to your GET or POST request. That can be done by using the AddRange method of your HttpWebRequest:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = 
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.foo.com");
myHttpWebRequest.AddRange(0,100);
```

That would yield the first 100 bytes. The server, however, needs to support this.

Comment: Although be advised that not all servers support the "Accept-Ranges" header. If a server doesn't support this, it might just send you the whole page, and it might return a `400 Bad Request`.

Comment: This did not work for the server we were trying. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The sort answer is not unless the web app supports some way to tailor it's response to what you want it to return.

This could take the form of a

- query string parameter
- header field value

The simplest way to add this would be a query string parameter and when detected write out the necessary HTML to the response object.  If you are unable to make changes to the web app then you won't be able to control how much of a page is returned to you.

You might want to read up on how [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) works since the question and it's answer relies upon this.  Specifically the [Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) Definition should be helpful.